# Can I replay heist missions in GTA V single player?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I got a lot of money from the first heist mission in GTA V.  Is it possible to play it again and get the same amount of money and/or level up the abilities of my crew?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can replay Heist missions using the Replay feature. However, doing so will not influence the rest of the game. You can neither improve your finances nor your crew by replaying Heists or any other missions.

Comment: On another note is there an option to play either choices of the heist?

Comment: Yes, you can choose your approach every time you replay a Heist mission (and no need to worry about the Heist setup missions as  those are skipped during replay.)

Answer (score 4):

Navigate the start menu, and you can replay a mission.  When you choose to do so, the game will notify you that it creates a save state of your current progress, allows you replay the past mission, and then restores that save state once the mission is completed.

You can't gain additional money, or level up your crew as nothing is saved from replaying missions.  You can, however, do the heists the second way (as most of them give you two approaches) to attempt the gold medal objectives, which will save if you achieve them.

Comment: do you get to keep the money if you play the other choice in the heist?

Comment: No, as stated in the answer, you cannot gain additional money. A save state is created at your furthest progress, and you play the mission in a sort of sandbox. Then the save state is restored and you are returned to your current progress.  No money, ammo, or anything except completing secondary objectives (for gold medals) will be saved from replaying missions

Answer (score 3):

Replaying missions has no influential ability on the game, anything you gain will be lost. It's just to improve if you feel you need to.

My friend tried to get into a rare car at the end of a mission, thinking he could drive away. Instead the screen faded and it loads back to the original game...